# Why can't i call my Onclick function in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-proptypes

My onClick function doesn't work and the problem is: "Line 17:  'propTypes' is not defined  no-undef
Line 18:  'propTypes' is not defined  no-undef".

my "text:propType.string" and "color:propTypes.string" are on line 17 and 18.
Thank you for helping me!

This is my Button.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const Button = ({color, text}) => {
    const onClick = () => {
        console.log('click')
    }
    
    return <button onClick={onClick} style={{backgroundColor:color}} className="btn">{text}</button>
        
}

Button.defaultProps = {
    color:'steelblue',

}
Button.propTypes={
    text:propTypes.string,
    color:propTypes.string,
}
export default Button
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update `propTypes` to `PropTypes`:

```
Button.propTypes={
    text:PropTypes.string,
    color:PropTypes.string,
}
```

Comment: omg it works! silly me! the spelling is so headache btw. thank you!